# PHPExcel creating file in binary format instead of xml

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to generate an Excel file.  The problem is that, instead of generating the file in XML format, it is being generated in binary format.

```
$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();
$phpExcel->getProperties()->setTitle($worksheet_title);
$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$worksheet = $phpExcel->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Field');
// ...
$phpExcelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, 'Excel2007');
$phpExcelWriter->save('tmp/xxx');
```

Since I am using the Excel2007 writer, it should be creating the output file in readable xml format, but it's being created in binary format, instead.

Comment: I believe 2003 is the xml format, 2007 was the binary version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OfficeOpenXML file is ***not*** directly human-readable as one gigantasaurus of an xml file. It is a zipped archive containing a collection of XML files.

Unzip the .xlsx file, then you will find a series of folders containing xml files.

That is what MS Excel generates when you save a file as xlsx, and it is what PHPExcel generates as well

You can look at this link for full details of the [OfficeOpenXML standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/TC45_available_docs.htm)